# How to create a hierarchy of a list of given paths that point so some value

Tags: python, dictionary

This is **not** a duplicate question, other questions that have already been asked do **not** solve this issue.

I want to be able to assign any value I want to the last item of each path as they represent some property that is a string. All solutions I have seen in other threads are either not compatible with my input or create a dictionary in a format that is not suitable for my use case. Therefore, I am asking my own question in *hope* for some guidance.

I have a list of paths like so:

```
paths = [
    "Properties/Static/E",
    "Properties/Static/Category1/A",
    "Properties/Static/Category2/Subcategory1/A",
    ...
    "Properties/Static/Category3/C"
]
```

Where the last component of each path is some string (and not a dictionary themselves).

And I want to create dictionary that represents the hierarchy of the paths - and the properties within - like so:

```
{
    "Properties": {
        "Static": {
            "E": *some_value*,
            "Category1": {
                "A": *some_value*,
                "Subcategory": {
                    "A": *some_value*
                }
            },
            ...
            "Category3": {
                "C": *some_value*
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where *some_value* would be fetched from some other function, but for this question though it can be assume it's an empty string.

I have tried using the following algorithm:

```
hierarchy_dict = {}
for path in paths:                
    current_dict = hierarchy_dict
    for level in path.split('/'):
        if level:                 
            current_dict = current_dict.setdefault(level, {})
```

Where it loops through each path and creates a dictionary for each level of the path but as it can be seen it creates the hierarchy like so:

```
{
    "Properties": {
        "Static": {
            "E": {},
            "Category1": {
                "A": {},
                "Subcategory": {
                    "A": {}
                }
            },
            ...
            "Category3": {
                "C": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where each last item is an empty dictionary which is obviously not what I want.

I tried this solution - albeit a bit messy:

```
hierarchy_dict = {}
for path in paths:                
    current_dict = hierarchy_dict
    for i, level in enumerate(path.split('/')):
        if level:
            # Check if item is the last level, and set to a value
            # In this case I try setting to an empty string for testing purposes
            if i = len(path.split('/')) - 1:
                current_dict[level] = ""
            else:
                current_dict = current_dict.setdefault(level, {})
```

But I get the following error `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the single equals-sign in `if i = len(path.split('/')) - 1:`, your code works just fine for me:

```
paths = [
    "Properties/Static/E",
    "Properties/Static/Category1/A",
    "Properties/Static/Category2/Subcategory1/A",
    "Properties/Static/Category3/C"
]

hierarchy_dict = {}
for path in paths:                
    current_dict = hierarchy_dict
    for i, level in enumerate(path.split('/')):
        if level:
            # Check if item is the last level, and set to a value
            # In this case I try setting to an empty string for testing purposes
            if i == len(path.split('/')) - 1:
                current_dict[level] = ""
            else:
                current_dict = current_dict.setdefault(level, {})

print(hierarchy_dict)
# {'Properties': {'Static': {'E': '', 'Category1': {'A': ''}, 'Category2': {'Subcategory1': {'A': ''}}, 'Category3': {'C': ''}}}}
```

I do however get the same error if I have paths like so:

```
paths = [
    "Properties/Static/Category1/A",
    "Properties/Static/Category1/A/B",
]

...

# TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

But I believe those should be invalid according to your description:

> Where the last component of each path is some string (and not a dictionary themselves).

And while it might not fix your error (it's unclear what should happen), you can simplify your code like so:

```
hierarchy_dict = {}
for path in paths:                
    current_dict = hierarchy_dict
    *parents, last = path.split('/')
    for parent in parents:
        current_dict = current_dict.setdefault(parent, {})
    current_dict[last] = ""
```